# iOS - replicating a constraint programmatically

Tags: ios, autolayout, uitextview, constraints

I created this constraint in Interface Builder. Without it, the below textview expands upwards as its content grows, with it, the textview expands downwards as its content grows.

[image]

How do I create that constraint in programmatically?

Here is what I tried:

```
    [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                          constraintWithItem:_textView
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                          toItem:_internalScrollView //this is the parent view
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                          multiplier:1.0f
                          constant:0.0]];
```

but it has no material affect on anything.

The UITextView object I am using is from this library https://github.com/MatejBalantic/MBAutoGrowingTextView but that is a red herring to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need to do.

```
[_internalScrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                          constraintWithItem:_textView
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                          toItem:_internalScrollView //this is the parent view
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                          multiplier:1.0f
                          constant:300.0]]; // constant should be 300 as shown by you in screen shot
```

btw, the above screen shot shows you are making constraint with top layout guide and not with parent view of textView if that is the case then layout attributes should be changed in the above code according to your needs